# How to dynamically allocate struct fields based on data read from binary file?

Tags: c

I have a structure that looks like this :

```
typedef struct Student {    //dynamically allocated structure
    char *first_name;
    char *last_name;
    float grade;
}Student;
```

What I want to do is to read data from a binary file and dynamically allocate memory for the **first_name** and **last_name** fields. I successfully completed this task when reading from a normal *.txt* file. Here is the code:

```
void Read_From_File(const char *file_name, Student *p_destination, const int number_of_students)
{
    FILE *p_file = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (!p_file)
    {
        perror("Error opening the file. \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int index = 0;
    while (index < number_of_students)
    {
        unsigned char buffer[256];
        fscanf (p_file, "%s", buffer);
        p_destination[index].last_name = (char*)malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
        strcpy(p_destination[index].last_name, buffer);

        fscanf(p_file, "%s", buffer);
        p_destination[index].first_name = (char*)malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
        strcpy(p_destination[index].first_name, buffer);

        fscanf(p_file, "%f", &p_destination[index].grade);
        index++;
    }
    fclose(p_file);
}
```

It was simple because *fscanf* can read data individually and has type specifiers, like the following : *%s last name* / *%s first name* / *%f grade*. I don't know how to use *fread* to read single pieces of data like I did with *fscanf*. 
Here is what I've tried so far, but it doesn't work:

```
int number_of_students = 0;
unsigned char buffer[256];
char file_name[10];
FILE *p_file = NULL;
Student *p_students = NULL;

printf("Enter file name. \n");
scanf("%s", file_name);

p_file = fopen(file_name, "rb");

fread(&number_of_students, sizeof(number_of_students), 1, p_file);
p_students = (Student *)malloc(number_of_students * sizeof(Student));
if (!p_students)
{
    perror("Could not allocate memory. \n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

for (int index = 0; index < number_of_students; ++index)
{
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 1, p_file);
    p_students[index].last_name = (char *)malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
    if (!p_students[index].last_name)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory. \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    strcpy(p_students[index].last_name, buffer);

    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 1, p_file);
    p_students[index].first_name = (char *)malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
    if (!p_students[index].first_name)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory. \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    strcpy(p_students[index].first_name, buffer);

    fread(&p_students[index].grade, sizeof(float), 1, p_file);
}
Print_Students(p_students, number_of_students);
```

Also, the *Print_Students* function looks like this:

```
void Print_Students(Student *p_students, int number_of_students)
{
    printf("================================================================================================\n");
    for (unsigned int index = 0; index < number_of_students; ++index)
    {
        printf("\t\t===================== Student %d =====================\n\n", index);
        printf("Last name: %s\n", p_students[index].last_name);
        printf("First name: %s\n", p_students[index].first_name);
        printf("Grade: %.2f\n", p_students[index].grade);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The input.txt file looks like this:

```
19
Terresa Minaya 9.50
Otto Pleiman 7 
Illa Holzman 5.25
Alona Greeson 3.40
Natalya Vickrey 10
Catrina Cho 9.34
Loida Dinapoli 9.43
Neely Mcelligott 8.30
Salome Urban 8.75
Rosetta Dagenhart 9.10
Diane Cooksey 10
Novella Longmire 3
Gilberte Manganaro 4
Joye Humbert 5
Justa Larock 6
Delana Bufkin 7
Genaro Kenison 8.98
Refugio Arena 4.56
Iona Nida 7.65
```

I loaded the data from this file in my vector of Students, and then I wrote the *input.bin* file using based on the data from my vector. I've used the following code to write to binary:

```
void Write_To_Binary(const char *file_name, Student *p_source, const int number_of_students)
{   
    size_t successfully_written = 0;
    FILE *p_file = fopen(file_name, "wb");
    if (!p_file)
    {
        perror("Error opening the file. \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    successfully_written = fwrite(&number_of_students, sizeof(number_of_students), 1, p_file);
    if (successfully_written != 1)
    {
        perror("Error writing to the file. \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    successfully_written = fwrite(p_source, sizeof(Student), number_of_students, p_file);
    if (successfully_written != number_of_students)
    {
        perror("Error writing all the student data. \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fclose(p_file);
}
```

UPDATE: I've followed iBug's solution and it worked. I changed the data fields as it follows: sizeof(last_name) last_name sizeof(first_name) first_name grade.

I'll post here the functions I've used to write to the bin file, and read from it.

Here is the function *Write_To_Binary*

```
    void Write_To_Binary(const char *file_name, Student *p_source, const unsigned int number_of_students)
{
    FILE *p_file = fopen(file_name, "wb");
    if (!p_file)
    {
        perror("Error opening the file. \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    size_t successfully_written = 0;
    successfully_written = fwrite(&number_of_students, sizeof(number_of_students), 1, p_file);
    if (successfully_written != 1)
    {
        printf("Error writing to the file. \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    unsigned int width = 0, width1 = 0;
    for (unsigned int index = 0; index < number_of_students; ++index)
    {
        width = strlen(p_source[index].last_name) + 1;

        successfully_written = fwrite(&width, sizeof(width), 1, p_file);
        printf("Name: %s Width: %d \n", p_source[index].last_name, width);
        if (successfully_written != 1)
        {
            printf("Error writing to the file. \n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        successfully_written = fwrite(p_source[index].last_name, width, 1, p_file);
        if (successfully_written != 1)
        {
            printf("Error writing to the file. \n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        width = strlen(p_source[index].first_name) + 1;

        successfully_written = fwrite(&width, sizeof(width), 1, p_file);
        if (successfully_written != 1)
        {
            printf("Error writing to the file. \n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        successfully_written = fwrite(p_source[index].first_name, width, 1, p_file);
        if (successfully_written != 1)
        {
            printf("Error writing to the file. \n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        successfully_written = fwrite(&p_source[index].grade, sizeof(float), 1, p_file);
        if (successfully_written != 1)
        {
            printf("Error writing to the file. \n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    fclose(p_file);
}
```

And here is the function *Read_From_Binary*

```
void Read_From_Binary(const char *file_name, Student *p_destination)
{
    FILE *p_file = fopen(file_name, "rb");
    if (!p_file)
    {
        perror("Error opening file. \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    unsigned int number_of_students = 0;
    size_t successfully_read;
    successfully_read = fread(&number_of_students, sizeof(number_of_students), 1, p_file);
    if (successfully_read != 1)
    {
        printf("Error reading the number of students. \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    unsigned int width = 0;
    for (unsigned int index = 0; index < number_of_students; ++index)
    {
        successfully_read = fread(&width, sizeof(width), 1, p_file);
        if (successfully_read != 1)
        {
            printf("Error reading from the file. \n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        p_destination[index].last_name = (char*)malloc(width);
        if (!p_destination[index].last_name)
        {
            printf("Could not allocate memory. \n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        successfully_read = fread(p_destination[index].last_name, width, 1, p_file);
        if (successfully_read != 1)
        {
            printf("Error reading from the file. \n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        successfully_read = fread(&width, sizeof(width), 1, p_file);
        if (successfully_read != 1)
        {
            printf("Error reading from the file. \n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        p_destination[index].first_name = (char*)malloc(width);
        if (!p_destination[index].first_name)
        {
            printf("Could not allocate memory. \n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        successfully_read = fread(p_destination[index].first_name, width, 1, p_file);
        if (successfully_read != 1)
        {
            printf("Error reading from the file. \n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        successfully_read = fread(&p_destination[index].grade, sizeof(float), 1, p_file);
        if (successfully_read != 1)
        {
            printf("Error reading from the file. \n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    fclose(p_file);
}
```

Comment: I see one possible problem: strlen(buffer) is not the size you need to allocate, you need strlen(buffer)*sizeof(char)

Comment: @Angen sizeof(char) is 1 in C (by language specification), so no.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 1, p_file);  2nd param is size of one element and 3th param is number of elements to be readed, so you are telling read one element of size char

Comment: Thanks, I can see the mistake, but how could I handle it? The names in the binary file are random, and I can't predict how long those names will be.

Assuming that I would need to replace sizeof(char) with something like strlen(last_name) * sizeof(char).

Comment: has your file any structures? which delimiters are used there? is every name, surname couple in new line?

Comment: Yes, it has. I've updated the original post.

Comment: Do you know about [strdup(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html)? Also read more carefully the documentation of [standard C functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) ....

Comment: Nope, I didn't know about it. I've thought about it, but in which context should I use that function? Or why did you ask about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did [a similar job](https://github.com/iBug/CGadgets/blob/master/MyVaultManager/file.h) in a recent project.

I implemented a binary file format on my own, and it's structure is

```
MAGIC
number of records
record 1
    (int) length of this record
    data
record 2
    (int) length of this record
    data
```

So you can pit an extra 4 bytes (or an integer) indicating the length of what to read, and read according to that number.

Advantages of this implementation are:

- You don't need another buffer to read first, which may add an extra limitation on lengths of records.
- When the content format changes, you don't have to worry about reading lengths.
- No single character needs to be used as "terminator" because the length is pre-determined.

Comment: This is a fine idea, but it would require some major changes in my code and in my input files. For now, I'll stick to the suggestion @Paul Ogilvie gave to me. However, I would like to try your suggestion too in the near future.

Comment: I'm sorry for responding this late. I gave your solution a try and it worked pretty well, I had only to rewrite the "write_to_binary" function and the "read_from_binary" one. Should I post my solution code in order to help others who might have the same problem?

Comment: @I.Silviu Surely. On Stack Overflow, you're always encouraged to post anything that you think may be helpful to further readers.

Comment: Ok, I've added it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the format of the file. I assume the following:

- the file starts with a four-byte integer that holds the number of students in the file.
- The data about each student is in the order First name, Last name, grade.
- The strings first and last name are terminated with a null byte.
- the float is a 4 byte float.
- Following the 4 byte float follows the next student (there is no record demarcation).

Now you can read the data. The only thing is how to determine the length of the strings as you have to allocate memory for them. There are two ways:

- use a buffer of reasonable size (say `buf[256]`) and read character by character until you see the null character (you may want to skip characters that would let the buffer overflow, so another part of the file format specification is that strings cannot be longer than 255). After reading and terminating the buffer with \0 call `strlen` and then allocate the string with `malloc`, or
- remember the current position, read character by character, counting them until you see the \0, allocate the memory, seek backwards and read the string.

Comment: About the third point, should my structured file records look like this?Terresa\0 Minaya\0 9.50

Comment: Your file should look like: any format that is specified and that you can read-in. If my assumed format doesn't fit, adapt my assumptions and adapt the method of reading in accordingly.